# Remove Only First Word From Given String

Tags: php, replace

I'm trying to remove first word from given string. I'm done so far...

```
$word = 'removeMe|meow|whatever';

$needle = 'removeMe';
$haystack = ''; // To replace with.

$word = str_replace( $needle, $haystack, $word );
```

It's working great, but problem is when *$word* is something like this...

```
$word = 'removeMe|meow|removeMe|whatever';
```

I don't want to remove second *$needle*. Is it possible and how? )

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to remove only the first occurrence of a given string or only if it appears at the beginning?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. Only, if it appears at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PHP doesn't support this by default. Here's a function doing it:

```
function str_replace_once($needle, $replace, $haystack){
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos === false) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    return substr_replace($haystack, $replace, $pos, strlen($needle));
}
```

If you want to replace the text only at the beginning of the string:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($word, '/').'/', '', $str);
```

If your string is actually a `|`-separated list, see @lonesomeday's answer.

Answer (score 4):

PHPs [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) supports this directly through the *limit* parameter

like:

```
# now: removeMe|meow|removeMe|whatever

$word = preg_replace("/$needle/", $haystack, $word, 1);

# now: |meow|removeMe|whatever
```

If your *needle* only appears **at the beginning**, sth. like a simple

```
$word = preg_replace("/^$needle/", $haystack, $word);
```

should suffice.

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 2):

Third parameter of the explode function limits how many times the word will be split. This allowed a very clean solution for me. From [php.net](http://php.net/explode):

> *If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>   maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of
>   string.*

```
$split = explode('|', $word, 2);
$word = $split[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$words = explode('|', $word);
if ($words[0] === $needle) {
    unset($words[0]);
}
$word = implode('|', $words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$index = strpos($word, '|');
$word = substr($word, 0, $index);
```

Comment: or `$index+1` to remove the `|` too.

Comment: That removes the first word *whether or not* it matches `$needle`. I don't think that's what the questioner wants (though I admit the question is vague).

Comment: I understood the question as "I want to remove the first word whatever it is" but maybe you're right. ThiefMaster understood the question differently too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna go with an explode, implode, but this is better and shorter. 
It will leave the first pipe symbol though.

echo $string = strstr($string , '|');

If your string is space separated, just replace the pipe with a space