# Match first word then remove it from string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string like this:

```
$subject = "This is just a test";
```

I want to find the first word then remove it from `$subject` in PHP. I use `preg_match` to get the first word but can I use a **single operation** to also remove it?

```
preg_match('/^(\w+)/', trim($subject), $matches);
```

After matching my first word the string should be

```
$subject = "is just a test";
```

and `$matches` should contain the first word

Comment: So you are stuck how to remove the first word? (Maybe `preg_replace()` ?!)

Comment: Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: preg_replace to match/capture the word, and replace it with an empty string...

Comment: How does preg_replace store the found matches? It returns the new string, not my matches. I don't want to only remove the first words but also to know what it is

Comment: @all you already did that part in your question.

Comment: So I should use both `preg_match` and `preg_replace`? I wonder if there's a single function/operation for this

Comment: Yes @DamienPirsy, `preg_match` stores the found matches while `preg_replace` removes them and returns what's left. I wanted a single function/operation to do all this

Comment: Maybe this could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210522/remove-only-first-word-from-given-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Preg_match` can capture, `preg_replace` can replace. I'd use the `preg_replace_callback`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php, to store your value and replace the original. I also modified your regex a bit you can swap it back to the `\w` if you find that is better. That will allow the line to start with `- and 0-9` as well though so no necessarily a word.

```
<?php
$subject = "This is just a test";
preg_replace_callback('~^([A-Z]+)\s(.*)~i', function($found) { 
        global $subject, $matches;
        $matches = $found[1];
        $subject = $found[2];
    }, $subject);
echo $subject . "\n";
echo $matches;
```

Output:

> is just a test
>   
> This

Comment: This is the one. I don't like that `global` there but what can I do? Thanks. Also, do I need PHP 5.3 for `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: You could pass `$matches` by using `use()` with reference and just assign the return value of: `preg_replace_callback` to `$subject` and then you can remove the: `global ...`

Comment: @ali ^ See my comment; You need PHP 5.3 because of the anonymous function

Answer (score 1):

Like chris' answer, my method relies on the fact that there will be at least 2 words in the substring separated by a single space.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/230d053c05266fff1fb81213ccf8c449b1978602))

```
$subject = "This is just a test";
$halves=explode(' ',$subject,2);  // create a two-element(maximum) array
$first=array_splice($halves,0,1)[0];  // assign first element to $first, now $halves is a single, reindexed element
$subject=$halves[0];
echo "First=$first and Subject=$subject";
// output: First=This and Subject=is just a test
```

Or you could more simply use this one-liner:

```
list($first,$subject)=explode(' ',$subject,2);  // limit the number of matches to 2
```

---

Or

```
echo "First=",strstr($subject,' ',true)," and Subject=",ltrim(strstr($subject,' '));
```

Or

```
echo "First=",substr($subject,0,strpos($subject,' '))," and Subject=",substr($subject,strpos($subject,' ')+1);
```

---

If you particularly want a regex solution for some crazy reason, `preg_split()` works just like `explode()`:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9acb0ab1f1fcbd9204a94572dc2558f65a59795d))

```
$subject = "This is just a test";
list($first,$subject)=preg_split('/ /',$subject,2);  // limit the number of matches to 2
echo "First=$first and Subject=$subject";
// output: First=This and Subject=is just a test
```